# Limited Area Pinchview in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, pinchzoom, pinch, uipinchgesturerecognizer

I have a label on a imageview and both of them are in one view. The label is pinch-able via below code. However, it is pinch-able also out of image view. I want the areas outside of the imageview not seen (like in whatsapp or snapchat. The texts outside of the screen is not seen, i want that for only imageview area). I'm not sure but i guess somehow it will be done with bring view to front function. Just i don't know how to do it

```
  func handlePinch(recognizer: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
        if let view = recognizer.view as? UILabel {
            let pinchScale: CGFloat = recognizer.scale
            view.transform = view.transform.scaledBy(x: pinchScale, y: pinchScale)
            recognizer.scale = 1.0
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you adding this in IB? Your handler function, with the info you provided, would have to do a hit test or something else I would think.

Comment: I'm adding it to pinchRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.handlePinch(recognizer:)))

Comment: actually this probably wont work, what does your "view.addgestureRecognizer(myGR)" look like?

Comment: It is like this and i solved the problem with below answer. mylabel.addGestureRecognizer(pinchRecognizer)

Answer (score 0):

I done it with creating views out of imageview (left, right upper and bottom side) and set all views to the front except the view which has imageview. I created the first three view in (left, right and the bottomside) in the storyboard and last one (the upper one) in the code because i needed to hide status bar first then create a view on top of it.

```
 customView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 440, height: 20))
        customView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        self.view.addSubview(customView)
        self.view.bringSubview(toFront: view_main)
        self.view.bringSubview(toFront: view2)
        self.view.bringSubview(toFront: view3)
        self.view.bringSubview(toFront: customView)
```